# How to use AND operator in elasticsearch to query nested fields?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, elasticsearch-2.0

I have 2 documents in elasticsearch in the below structure:

Document 1:

```
{
  "specification": [
                    {
                     "name": "Processor",
                     "value": "Intel"
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "RAM",
                     "value": "2GB"
                    }
                   ]
}

Document 2:
{
  "specification": [
                    {
                     "name": "Processor",
                     "value": "Intel"
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "RAM",
                     "value": "3GB"
                    }
                   ]
}
```

I want to get the document that have a specification with values intel and 2GB (i.e) 1st document. But when i try to use must (AND operator) i am getting nothing. If i use should (OR operator) i am getting both the documents. Can anyone help me on this? Below is my query..

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "specification",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [

                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            { "match": { "specification.name": "Processor" }},
                            { "match": { "specifications.value": "Intel" }}
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            { "match": { "specification.name": "RAM" }},
                            { "match": { "specifications.value": "2GB" }}
                        ]
                    }
                }
              ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "specification",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "specification.name": "Processor"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "specification.value": "Intel"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "specification",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "specification.name": "RAM"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "specification.value": "2GB"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```